# Interfaces and their usage

Tags: java

```
public class MinimumEditDistance {
    public interface CostFunction{
        public int cost(int[][] distanceMatrix,CharSequence x, CharSequence y,int i,int j);
    }
    public static final CostFunction ONE = new CostFunction() {
        public int cost(int[][] distanceMatrix, CharSequence x, CharSequence y, int i, int j) {
            return 1;
        }
    };

    public static final CostFunction TWO = new CostFunction() {
        public int cost(int[][] distanceMatrix, CharSequence x, CharSequence y, int i, int j) {
            return 2;
        }
    };
```

I am not able to understand what actually is done in this code!!! What does `new` signify before `CostFunction()`. Actually, I am quite messed up in understanding this!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html). What you have there is an anonymous inner implementation of the inner interface, and is a very dirty example, that is why you have trouble understanding it.

If you were to split it apart, you'd have:

-a stand alone ConstFunction interface

```
public interface CostFunction{
  public int cost(int[][] distanceMatrix,CharSequence x, CharSequence y,int i,int j);
}
```

-a stand alone ConstFunction implementation named CostFunctionOne

```
public class CostFunctionOne{
  public int cost(int[][] distanceMatrix, CharSequence x, CharSequence y, int i, int j) {
    return 1;
  }
};
```

-a stand alone ConstFunction implementation named CostFunctionTwo

```
public class CostFunctiontTwo{
  public int cost(int[][] distanceMatrix, CharSequence x, CharSequence y, int i, int j) {
    return 2;
  }
};
```

-a stand alone MinimumEditDistance class using the above

```
public class MinimumEditDistance{
  public static final CostFunction ONE = new CostFunctionOne();
  public static final CostFunction TWO = new CostFunctionTwo();
}
```

Although they might be ugly, sometimes you'll chose to have such a quick implementation for an interface because you can access the variables and methods from the container class. You'll see a lot of them when using listeners.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an anonymous implementation of CostFunction interface. Just like if you'd have created a class implementing this interface and created an instance of this class.
**EDIT:** I mean, instances of *two* different classes, 'cause there are two implementations in your code.

Comment: "It's just an anonymous implementation of CostFunction interface."
What does that mean iozee? means then what are ONE and TWO in this code - variables, objects what? 
And if they are instances of two different classes then what does "public static final CostFunction ONE means? Is it the instance of CostFunction because that is not possible, right?

Comment: @user1468694 It's just like declaring CostFunctionImpl class that implements CostFunction interface and then assigning **new CostFunctionImpl()** to ONE, same with TWO but there'll be an instance of CostFunctionImpl2 for example.

Comment: @user1468694 public static final CostFunction ONE means that ONE is *of type* CostFunction. When you implement an interface of a class, it's instances are also of type CostFunction, in addition to the type of the class. I mean, in this context, we're not interested in the class of the object attached to ONE, but what type it is.

Comment: Are ONE and TWO the instances of the same class or different classes means suppose if ONE is an instance of "AnonymousInnerClass1" then is TWO also an instance of this class or "AnonymousInnerClass2"? This is my main doubt.

Comment: @user1468694 Yes, they're the instances of differemnt classes. therefore, it's more convenient to make an anonymous (with no class declaration) implementation, what you see in our code. Moreover, this implementation is not reused in your code, so there's no need to write tons of classes for implementations you use in one place.

Answer (score 1):

The instantiation of `ONE` and `TWO` is creating anonymous classes that implements the CostFunction interface, hence why you see the `cost` method being implemented in the same block of code.

Have a look at this [page](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) that talks about anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

That is the usage of Anonymous inner class.

```
public static final CostFunction ONE = new CostFunction() {
    public int cost(int[][] distanceMatrix, CharSequence x, CharSequence y, int i, int j) {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

This creates a class CostFunction$1.class by javac

```
class 'Anonymous inner class' implements CostFunction {
    public int cost(int[][] distanceMatrix, CharSequence x, CharSequence y, int i, int j) {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Are ONE and TWO the instances of the same class or different classes means suppose if ONE is an instance of "AnonymousInnerClass1" then is TWO also an instance of this class or "AnonymousInnerClass2"? This is my main doubt.

Answer (score 0):

basically you are implementing the interface and creating an anonymous class.. To see the working of this just run the following code:

```
public class Main{
    public interface CostFunction{
        public int cost();
    }
    public static final CostFunction ONE = new CostFunction() {
        public int cost() {
            return 1;
        }
    };

    public static final CostFunction TWO = new CostFunction() {
        public int cost() {
            return 2;
        }
    };
     public static void main (String[] args)
     {
      System.out.println(ONE.cost());
     }
}
```